# I want to use characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index method of NSString class

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I want to compare the value returned by characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
of NSString class with a another NSString having one character stored in it any suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the top of my head, you can compare them directly using characterAtIndex on the other NSString as well.

```
if([string characterAtIndex:index] == [stringWithOneChar characterAtIndex:0]){
   // Do something here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *temp = @"Hello";
NSString *temp2 = @"H";

if([temp characterAtIndex:0] == [temp2 characterAtIndex:0] )
```